# iOS PJSIP Error: Address already in use

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, pjsip

I am using PJSIP to establish a SIP connection. 
The first connection works fine. However, when stopping the connection and reestablishing the connection afterwards I am always receiving the following error message:

```
Error creating SIP TCP listener: Address already in use [status=120048]
```

What can I do about this? Is there any specific method that needs to be called to release the TCP ports?

Comment: are you using multiple accounts for sip registration? is so define different port for every account..or deregister the other accounts......

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that You did not kill the app successfully and local address Your are trying to start is in use.

However i am not a programmer.
Maybe You should try with pj_status_t pjsua_transport_close  :

http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__TRANSPORT.htm#gac07273ce5b82c2ddf8e15872068304d3